# Passing inputs to Commands in Command line for user prompt

Tags: shell, command-line, command, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

Suppose I execute a command which prompts the user for input. Is there a way by which I can pass the input in the command itself, rather than taking the input from the user. Like for example, in cloning a private github repo I type:

```
!git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

instead I want to do something like

```
!echo "username" | git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git.
```

Instead of echo can I have something which automatically inputs username when prompted, by reading it from a file or specifying it directly in my command?

Thanks for helping!